# Quartic inequality

Tags: functions, inequality

I am a physics student and for a physical system, I end up with the  following quartic inequality

$(x^2+\frac{1}{2})(x^2 + 1) < 0.$

Does there exist a solution to this inequality? It appears that $-1\le x^2 \le -1/2$. I think it does not make any sense!

Comment: This is self-explanatory: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/88tlg7rrxt

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality has no real solutions because $x^2+1>0$ and $x^2+\frac{1}{2}>0.$

Your way
$$-1<x^2<-\frac{1}{2}$$ says the same.

Comment: What about complex solutions?

Comment: You can not  solve inequalities in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $x^{2}+1\geq 1$, so $\left(x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)(x^{2}+1)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}>0$, so that inequality does not hold for real number $x$.

Comment: Is there any possibility of a complex solution?

Comment: The point is, there is no inequality in the complex field.